# NullPointerException when Initializing new object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a class called CustomerRecord, that another Class, CustomerList contains. When Customer List initializes, everything is fine, but when the first instance of Customer record initializes I get a Null Pointer Exception. Im not sure why this keeps happening but I would much appreciate some help on what is wrong and how to fix it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at CustomerList.getCustomerList(CustomerList.java:31)
at Assignment3.main(Assignment3.java:16)
```

Here is my code

```
public class CustomerRecord {

    private int customerNumber;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double balance;



    public CustomerRecord() {
        super();
    }
    public int getCustomerNumber() {
        return customerNumber;
    }
    public void setCustomerNumber(int customerNumber) {
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return this.customerNumber  + " " + this.firstName  + " " + this.lastName  + " " + this.balance;

    }


}
```

Here is my CustomerList Code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CustomerList {

private int count;
private CustomerRecord[] data;

public CustomerList(){
    count = 0;
    CustomerRecord[] data = new CustomerRecord[100];
    }

public void getCustomerList (String fileName){
    Scanner fileScan;

    try {
        fileScan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        while (fileScan.hasNext()){
            if (fileScan.hasNextInt()){
                int customerNumber = fileScan.nextInt();
                String firstName = fileScan.next();
                String lastName = fileScan.next();
                double TransactionAmount = fileScan.nextDouble();

                data[customerNumber].setBalance(data[customerNumber].getBalance() + TransactionAmount);
            }
            else{
                data[count] = new CustomerRecord();
                data[count].setCustomerNumber(count);
                data[count].setFirstName(fileScan.next());
                data[count].setLastName(fileScan.next());
                data[count].setBalance(fileScan.nextDouble());
                count++;
                }           
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public CustomerRecord getCustomer (int customerNumber){
    if (data[customerNumber] != null){
        return data[customerNumber];
    }
    else
        return null;

}
```

}

Comment: where is your main method?

Comment: Where is `CustomerList` class? It's the one throwing exception. No issues in this Class AFAIF.

Comment: I added the CustomerList class

Comment: how many elements you have in your filename file?

Comment: data[count] = new CustomerRecord();   This is line 31

Comment: I was testing it with three sets of data if thats what you mean

Comment: you used super() in your customerrecord class but I do not see any extends in your class signature?

Comment: That wasn't supposed to be there, auto generated and has been removed, it didn't change anything.

Comment: Yes I can, should I post here or can I message you my user name? Im new here sorry

Comment: @KickButtowski someone below solved it while I was resetting my Skype password :) Thank you so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialized data in the constructor you weren't actually referring to the same 'data' you had defined. You created a new data and set it to have 100 positions. But you defined it inside the constructor, so it didn't affect your global variable. What you need to do is replace `CustomerRecord[] data = new CustomerRecord[100];` for `data = new CustomerRecord[100];`

Comment: I am going to name my first child after you!

Comment: That was the issue, I thought it was something simple and obvious I just couldn't find it for anything thank you so so so much!